# How to pass data to another .Net Core web application using post

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a use case where I need to redirect to another web app but pass it some string data. What is the best way to do this? Should I use a query string or instead of controller code store the data in the web browser - not sure how to do this in .Net. Below I want to send the urlToReturn to the app I am re-directing to:

```
  [HttpPost]
  public IActionResult Index()
  {
      string urlToReturn = "http://consumingapp.com";

      return Redirect("https://ComponentApp.azurewebsites.net";
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Index()
{
  string urlToReturn = "http://consumingapp.com";

  return Redirect($"https://ComponentApp.azurewebsites.net?redirectTo={urlToReturn}";
}
```

Comment: Hiya, the problem with query string is that it manipulated on the other site so I need another method for this